# Hard drive board replacing Western Digital

Tags: hard-drive, backup, data-recovery, hardware-failure

I have a HDD: **Western Digital Caviar 8E 80gb**

**MDL:** WD800JD-75MSA3

**DCM:** H8BANTJCA

It's not working (head is not moving). So maybe it's an electronic failure.
I'll give it a shot. I want to replace the board. I find a board in another HDD. It's WD800JB 80gb.

I don't have any experience in this, so first question:
Can i replace with this board(WD800JB), or only with WD800JD ?

Both HDD @7200rpm.

Final question: is it important to match the **MDL** numbers, too ? (75MSA3)

Comment: I had a Seagate Drive do this and the recovery company tried two sets of electronics and could not recover the drive. I had to scrap it. Yes, a Clean Room was used.

Comment: All drive model numbers must match, and some others besides. The original board will have a chip containing drive specific information that must be transferred over. If not done properly the drive will likely not work. All drive repairs should be considered temporary and only for the purposes of data recovery, not for continued use of the drive. I know this only from reading about it.

Comment: How do you know the head is not moving? Did you open it to see?

Comment: @LMiller7 yes, I want to only recover my data, just I don't want to pay a lot of money for that. Not so important.

Comment: @Tetsujin no sound, HDD is not detected by Bios and I can't feel any "slight vibration".

Comment: Might not even be spinning up then

Comment: Have you verified the issue is indeed the drive (i.e. not the Power header/connector if using an extension, SATA connector, or the SATA cable)? Does the BIOS/UEFI detect the drive?